# Storybook does not support NextJS alias path ('@/')

Tags: next.js, storybook

Within my NextJS app, Storybook doesn't support imports starting with `@/`. For example, I get errors such as `Error: Can't resolve '@/lib/mylib'`.

How can I configure Storybook to support such an alias path?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `.storybook/main.js` or `.storybook/main.ts` to declare this path to Webpack:

```
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  ...,
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.resolve ??= {};
    config.resolve.alias ??= {};
    config.resolve.alias["@"] = path.resolve(__dirname, "../src");
    return config;
  }
};
```

Comment: I dont know why this wasnt in documentation